# Using dcast on my data frame is taking so much time to generate a wide format data?

Tags: r, reshape2

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(new, Subscriber_code ~ series, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "Views_Total")
```

There are around 340 series and its taking forever to generate a wide format data. I have around 1 million `subscriber_codes`. Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dcast` from `library(data.table)`.  It should be fast compared to the current option.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(new), Subscriber_code ~ series, fun.aggregate = sum, 
            value.var = "Views_Total")
```